# Getting the text file's url instead of the content in java when reading txt file into a variable

Tags: java, android

I'm new in java, and im trying to read a text file from the web into a variable, but i'm getting the text file's url, instead of the content, and just can't figure out what could be the problem.

The class where i'm trying to read the file:

```
public class readtextfile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

private TextView description;
public readtextfile(TextView descriptiontext){
    this.description = descriptiontext;
    }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    URL url = null;
    String result ="";
    try {

        url = new URL("http://example.com/description1.txt");       
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result+=line;
        }
        in.close();

        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return result;
}

 protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    //called when the background task makes any progress
 }

  protected void onPreExecute() {
     //called before doInBackground() is started
 }

@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    this.description.setText(result); 
 }
  }
```

The Activity where i call the class:

```
public class PhotosActivity extends Activity {

    TextView description;
    String descriptiontext;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout);

        description = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.description1));

        new readtextfile(description).execute();
        }   

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try url.openConnection and the use connection object to get inputStream. The updated method would be like

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    URL url = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.example.com/description1.txt");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Update based on your comment.**

You need not invoke the postExecute method. If you invoke postExecute it just execute that method. The doInBackground wont get exeuted. Instead you should use the execute method. Just like java thread.start() method invoke the overridden run() method.

When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:

> **onPreExecute()**, invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
> by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> **doInBackground(Params...)**, invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
> to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
> parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
> result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
> passed back to the last step. This step can also use
> publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
> These values are published on the UI thread, in the
> onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> **onProgressUpdate(Progress...)**, invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
> undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
> user interface while the background computation is still executing.
> For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
> a text field.
>
> **onPostExecute(Result)**, invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background
> computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

from [developer doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I updated the method, but it's still gives back the url. Maybe the problem is at the calling line in the Activity?
new readtextfile(description).onPostExecute("http://www.example.com/description1.txt");

Comment: Oh sorry.. I didnt notice that.. Instead of invoking onPostExecute directly try execute() method. Like new readtextfile(description).execute();

Comment: Alright, i have tried the execute method, but now im getting empty result. Damn.

Comment: Sure, i've updated the code. Could you review it again please?

Comment: This is working fine for me. Please make sure that the url connection could be established. Check for Log cat trace and see any unknown host exception is occuring or not?

Comment: OH GOD, i haven't gave internet permission to the application! As soon as i can i'll try it, but im sure that's the problem. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Scanner` like this.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/description1.txt");       
Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
```